# Silverstripe 4 SiteConfig logo image was not showed in template

Tags: php, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I create custom field for logo upload in `SiteConfig` and after uploading logo in `Settings` and trying to render it in `.ss` template. After rendering nothing was showed in template. This code i use in `Silverstripe v3` and all work good. Now in `v4` not work.

**Here is my `Extension`:**

```
class SiteConfigExtension extends \SilverStripe\ORM\DataExtension
{
    private static $db = array (
        'FacebookLink' => 'Varchar',
        'TwitterLink' => 'Varchar',
        'GoogleLink' => 'Varchar',
    );

    private static $has_one = array(
        'Logo' => Image::class,
        'DefaultImage' => Image::class
    );

    public function updateCMSFields(FieldList $fields)
    {
        parent::updateCMSFields($fields);


        $fields->addFieldsToTab('Root.Social', array (
            TextField::create('FacebookLink','Facebook'),
            TextField::create('TwitterLink','Twitter'),
            TextField::create('GoogleLink','Google'),
        ));

        $fields->addFieldsToTab('Root.Main', array(
            $logo = UploadField::create('Logo', 'Logo'),
            $defaultImage = UploadField::create('DefaultImage', 'Default Image'),
        ));

        $logo->setFolderName('Logo');
        $defaultImage->setFolderName("Settings");
    }
}
```

**Here is my template file `header.ss`:**

```
    <% with $SiteConfig %>
                    <div style="display: inline-block;">
                    <div style="float: left;">
                        <h1 id="logo">
                            <% if $Logo %>
                                <a>$Logo.SetWidth(50)</a>
                            <% end_if %>
                        </h1>
                    </div>
                    <div id="logo-tagline" style="float:left;">
                        <% if $Title %>
                            <h1>$Title</h1>
                        <% end_if %>
                        <% if $Tagline %>
                            <strong>$Tagline</strong>
                        <% end_if %>
                    </div>
                </div>
<% end_with %>
```

What i miss? What i do wrong ? Thanks for answer.

Comment: According to this http://api.silverstripe.org/4/SilverStripe/Assets/Image.html ss4 doesn't seem to have setWidth https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/files/images/

Answer (score 2):

Images are versioned in SilverStripe 4, so you'll need to ensure that the image gets published when you save your SiteConfig object.

You don't mention which version of SilverStripe 4 you're using - [this issue](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-siteconfig/commit/8e079023b95987ef142c4ed1e333f46560430ce2#diff-b8565993339e116120f7466b09573afd) has been looked at in 4.1.2 and 4.2.0-beta1 so far. This would mean that if you apply [the ownership API](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/model/versioning/#dataobject-ownership) to these related objects then they will be automatically published when the SiteConfig model is saved, e.g.:

```
private static $owns = ['Logo', 'DefaultImage'];
```

If you're using SilverStripe 4.1.2 or newer then the above is all you'll need to do.

For versions earlier than this, you can implement your own hook in your your SiteConfigExtension:

```
public function onAfterWrite()
{
    if ($this->owner->Logo()->exists()) {
        $this->owner->Logo()->publishSingle();
    }
    // ... same for other has_ones that are versioned
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer, i read this links and i try your example and not working again. In my `SiteConfigExtension` i put `$owns = ['Logo']` and `dev/build?flush=1` and reupload image and save in `Settings` page then in `.ss` template try to call `<img src='$SiteConfig.Logo.URL'>` and again nothing was showed. But image success uploaded and saved. My version is `4.1.0`

Comment: Update: I also after save `SiteConfig` go in assets and found uploaded logo an manualy i publish him. After refreshing front page again nothing

Comment: Ok, if you're manually published the image and it doesn't show up then you're probably doing something wrong in your template. The comment on your question indicates you might be using the wrong width method - maybe try `ScaleWidth` instead. Also if you are not using 4.1.2 you'll probably need to try my second example

Answer (score 1):

In SilverStripe version 4 the scaling for images in the templates has been changed and SetWidth is no longer used in SilverStripe 4.

In version 3 the scaling was done via

```
SetWidth(200)
```

In version 4 this changed to

```
ScaleWidth(200)
```

If you change this in your template this might fix your problem.